# p:selectManyCheckbox preloading

Tags: jsf, primefaces

For a project I have a list of default `subprojects` (e.g. Design, Implementation, Testing) or I can also define my own subproject. I store the `subprojects` in the database and when I edit this project I would like to load all the default `subprojects` in a `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` but with the ones previously existent as checked.

Here is my .xhtml so far:

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{add_project.selectedItems}"
                      id="selectedSubprojects"
                      layout="pageDirection"
                      converter="sub_conv_add_subproject">

    <f:selectItems value="#{add_project.availableItems}"
                   var="wws"
                   itemValue="#{wws}"
                   itemLabel="#{wws.subprojectName}"/>

</p:selectManyCheckbox>

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBoxOtherUpdate" itemLabel="Other" value="#{add_project.checked}">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="hiddingPanel"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:panel id="hiddingPanel">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{add_project.checked}">
        <p:inputText value="#{add_project.personalizedSubproject}"
                     id="personalizedSubprojectName"
                     styleClass="inputFieldWithoutMargin"/>

        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{add_project.submit}" styleClass="button">
            <f:ajax execute="subprojectPanelGrid" render="subprojectPanelGrid msgs2" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

`<f:selectedItems>` is my list of selected `subprojects` and `availableItems` is my list with all default `subprojects`.

Could you give me some advice on how to do this?

Comment: I've just have glanced at `selectManyCheckbox` code, and that should be render all your `availableItems` checkbox and `subproject` should the checked ones. Do you have this output? Do you want something different?

Comment: Yes the selectedItems should be the checked ones but what I want is when I display the selectManyCheckbox is to have some of the items from the checkbox already checked depending on what I have in my  database.

Comment: If `availableItems` comes from your database you should have the right outcome. What do you see now when `selectManyCheckbox` is rendered? In which property do you put you DB data?

Comment: Here is an example of what I want: I have the following items in the selectMultipleCheckbox: A,B,C. I click on B and C and I add them to the database. Now I want to edit my selection so I want to have displayed A, B(selected), C(selected).

Comment: You should put  your selected element fetched from DB into `availableItems` and take a `selectManyCheckbox update`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution but this only displays for me the items from the DB? I would like the user to also have the possibility when editing to choose from the ones previously not selected.